# GoogleApiClient Vs LocationClient to get accurate location in Android

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

I am trying to get an accurate location for my emergency alert app. I am already using the locationManager to get the location but fetching location with this technique takes about 30seconds I am looking for faster & accurate way.

The main goal here is to get faster/accurate location (Indoor or outdoor).

I have decided to use GooglePlayservices API for this purpose. I figured out there are two options LocationClient and GoogleApiClient?

I am not sure what is best here? Can somebody tell me what is the difference with both or is there a better option?

Let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GoogleApiClient` location client is good if you need a **fused** high accuracy location.

With **fused** I mean a location calculated using Wifi, GPS and so on.

With the location client, instead, you have to select a provider. You can even use a criteria, but in this case I think the information is not "fused". In your case I think the best choice is to use the `GoogleApiClient` location client and you can use `getLastLocation()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use GooglePlayServices, not only by the reasons @gresywolf82 hasstated, but also because it is most stable way of getting Location data.
In my experience I have encountered that some Android Devices may have issues obtaining location from the SDK's locationManager, this is due to probable bugs in the SDK, you can check an issue in the Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker regarding this problem with the locationManager  [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57707)

I have found the previous problem myself while using the locationManager and had absolutely no issues when switching to Google Play Services API.

SO in conclusion, not just for more precision but also for better stability within various devices I definitely recommend using Google Play Services API.

Answer (score 1):

Both LocationClient and GoogleApiClient provide fused locations.
It is the LocationManager where you need to specify your own providers, this is a low level access if you want to roll your own.

As far as I can see, the GoogleApiClient is an aggregate of LocationClient and other GoogleApis (someone pls. correct if I'm mistaken). If you only wish to target LocationClient you may do so without any Activity compliance.

On the other hand, it would appear that GoogleApiClient requires tight coupling with the Activity life cycle, needing to be disconnected onStop and connected onStart. The trouble I have with such asynchronous calls is trying to make sure the API is up and ready by the time I need it. Therefore I usually go with LocationClient and keep it running outside of Activity lifecycles.

This works, but if you have issues with power consumption you may want to disconnect when app is in background, and reconnect when app comes into foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use GoogleApiClient. It is old and problematic. Use the new API. Please read the following Android newsletter link for the details :
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/06/reduce-friction-with-new-location-apis.html